# Canon EOS 2000D: Where is the built in flash?

Tags: canon, flash

I am planning to buy the Canon EOS 2000D camera. I know it has a built in flash but I don't know where it is (I also looked in the specifications/other sites)? Is it a pop-up flash in the top and middle of the camera?

Comment: Did you try searching [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=canon+eos+"t7"+pop-up+flash&tbm=isch)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [this photo](https://www.teknowifi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/canon-t7-flash-1.jpg) to see where is the flash. The simplest way to use/open it is to press the button below the flash (marked with flash sign).

Also you can check on page 198 of the camera manual how to enable/disable flash.

Comment: It's pretty much the same for all Canon cameras with pop-up flash, but the image is of the wrong model camera.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also tell me if it pops-up by itself when I enable flash in the settings?

Comment: I know. I saw the model on the bottom.

Comment: @manarinian, the flash will pop-up when you shoot in Auto mode. For the Av,Tv,P, M you should pop-up it.